# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (columns and values are equal)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the error: `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

I think, normally this error occurs if the count of the columns and the values aren't equal, but in my code they are...(3).

This is my php code:

```
    $tempsongtitel = $_POST['songtitle'];
    $tempinterpret = $_POST['interpret'];
    $templink = $_POST['link'];

    $query = mysql_query("insert into tMusic (Songtitel, Interpret, Link) values ('$tempsongtitel, $tempinterpret, $templink')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to quote each individual value instead of one big quote around all of them.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), even if you fix your query as per @Don'tPanic's suggestion.

Comment: If you use PDO/prepared statements, it will eliminate the possibility of this specific problem, among other great benefits.

Comment: No problem. If you are going to do it this way, you should at least escape those post values before using them in your query.

Comment: Do you mean with mysql_escape_string() ?

Comment: If you must use mysql functions, that would be the one.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some quotes.  Should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into tMusic (Songtitel, Interpret, Link) values ('$tempsongtitel', '$tempinterpret', '$templink')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Otherwise, you were trying to insert all three POST values into the first field.

Moreover, the mysql_ extension has been deprecated and is on the way out and is highly discouraged, especially if you are creating new software.

AND I'll presume you are first sanitizing your data?  You're not really taking user input and placing it directly into the database, are you?  Even if you don't do any data validation, you should escape your data in the query... easiest and most foolproof way to do that is by using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that your values are all in one set of quotes instead of quoted individually. I think this is a pretty common error, and in my experience it is an easy mistake to make, but not immediately obvious when scanning over your code. You can fix it like this (quick fix, still using deprecated mysql, but with post values escaped):

```
$tempsongtitel = mysql_escape_string($_POST['songtitle']);
$tempinterpret = mysql_escape_string($_POST['interpret']);
$templink = mysql_escape_string($_POST['link']);

$query = mysql_query("insert into tMusic (Songtitel, Interpret, Link) 
    values ('$tempsongtitel', '$tempinterpret', '$templink')") or die(mysql_error());
```

If you can, it would be much better to update your code to use PDO. You could use a prepared statement like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tMusic (Songtitel, Interpret, Link) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $tempsongtitel);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $tempinterpret);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $templink);
$stmt->execute();
```

Among the many benefits of using this database extension rather than the old mysql functions it should not be possible to make an error like this in your code. In the prepared statement, there are no quotes around the parameter markers, so if you have `VALUES ('?, ?, ?')`, or even `VALUES ('?', '?', '?')` You would get bind errors when trying to bind the values, and the problem would become apparent pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, even though it's not 100% necessary and it's more time consuming, properly quoting and backticking EVERYTHING helps prevent this from happening.

```
$myQuery = "INSERT INTO `tMusic` (
                              `Songtitel`, 
                              `Interpret`, 
                              `Link`
                           ) VALUES (
                              '$tempsongtitel', 
                              '$tempinterpret', 
                              '$templink'
                           );";
$runQuery = mysqi_query($DBi, $myQuery) or die(mysqli_error($DBi));
```

The formatting you use is up to you but this helps me make sure I have a one to one relationship and that I've quoted everything.

Of course that's using `mysqli_*` in place of the deprecated `mysql_*` functions AND that's assuming you've set `$tempsongtitel`, `$tempinterpret` and `$templink` properly.